# what does "POR" mean in embedded development?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, arm

We have a third party device we are trying to integrated into our system and one of the things our code should do is start a hardware reset by asserting a reset pin. One of the documents mentions the pin being released before the end of POR. I bit of Google has given me [this](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Power+on+Reset) but I just wanted to confirm and understand if I am on the correct page.

Comment: You probably didn't need to ask this troll. Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_reset

Comment: Thanks. I did come across the Wikipedia entry but I just wanted to confirm as it was written with uppercase "O" in out datasheet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Power On Reset